# Custom button not appearing in my viewController after importing it

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a custom button and import in my viewController to reduce the code inside it. However, it is not working. Could anyone give me any hint?

Despite the class ButtonView was instantiated properly, the button not show.

**ButtonView.swift**

```
    import UIKit

final class ButtonView: UIButton {

    // MARK: - Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Private functions
    private func setupLayout() {
        setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 94/255, green: 162/255, blue: 58/255, alpha: 1)
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

**HomeController.swift**

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Properties
    var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    //MARK: - Views
    private let button = ButtonView()

    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupLayout()
        configureNavigationBar()
    }

    fileprivate func setupLayout() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(button)

        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = false

}
...
```

Comment: This code seems fine. You need to check if how you are displaying `HomeController` is correct.

Comment: `button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = false` why its false ?

Comment: button constraints are not correct

Comment: Oh, I tried out on iPhone 8 plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint that positions the button vertically is not active, change it to `true`:

```
button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

Comment: Shame on me hahaha